# API Platform: Session was used while the request was declared stateless

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I booted up the Symfony demo and created a new API resource using the MakerBundle.

`$ php bin/console make:entity --api-resource`

Now I can navigate to `/api` to check out my new resource.

The GET request works fine, but when I try out the POST request, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "@id": "/api/errors/500",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "title": "An error occurred",
  "detail": "Session was used while the request was declared stateless.",
  "status": 500,
  "type": "/errors/500",
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/home/paul/git/symfodemo/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "onKernelResponse",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\AbstractSessionListener",
      "type": "->"
    },
...
  ],
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Session was used while the request was declared stateless."
}
```

I am using Symfony 7.

Is there a known fix? Have I done something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: In api_platform.yaml you have 
stateless: true changed in false

Comment: @SasaMilivojevic Thanks for the workaround! I would be curious to know if the issue is known or if a proper fix exists.

Comment: also this comment
#      standard_put: true
and this
#  formats:
#    jsonld: [ 'application/ld+json' ]

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this is an answer

> In api_platform.yaml you have stateless: true changed in false –  Sasa Milivojevic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).